# Implementing Running Hours function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I was in the process of implementing a running hours function in PowerShell when I thought there must be an easier way to do this.

I want to submit the start time and end time e.g. 1800 and I want the function to block while outside working hours.

```
Function Stop-OutsideRunningHours
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    PARAM
    (
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $True )]
        [string]
        $StartTime = "1800",

        [string]
        $FinishTime = "0800",

        [int]
        $SleepFor = 60
    )

    Do
    {
        # block whilst outside working hours
    }
    While( $OutsideWorkingHours -eq $True )
}
```

Has anyone implemented something similar to this.

I am ready for your one liners ;)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for requests to improve existing, working code.

Comment: You might want to include your code so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: `I want the function to block while outside working hours.` Why? This is absolutely a case for using an actual scheduling system than blocking. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/12/introduction-to-powershell-scheduled-jobs/

Comment: @user9993 Yeah, that makes sense where a script can pick up from where it left off. However, I have a single task that needs to be run over several days and if the script crashes it is nearly impossible to tell whether the job is in a state where it can be restarted. This means I have to restart from scratch.

Comment: Then you may want to use a [workflow](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/08/19/powershell-workflow-for-mere-mortals-part-1/) rather than plain PowerShell.

Comment: PowerShell Workflows seems really interesting. Certainly the state persisting functionality. But am I right in assuming that stopping the workflow between a time period still has to be implemented in the script?

Comment: I don't have much experience with workflows (mostly because they behave subtly different from regular PowerShell, which is a pain), but from my understanding workflows should always be restartable, so suspending wouldn't be required.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `throw` keyword will exit your function and write the text that follows as an error. There are more sophisticated methods, but here's a one-liner:

```
if(!((get-date -Format HHMM).ToString() -gt 0600 -and (get-date -Format HHMM).ToString() -lt 1800)){throw "no workee workee"}
```